# Is an MFCC a linear transform?

Tags: mfcc, source-separation

Can one determine if an MFCC vector represents a combination of two sounds whose MFCCs were previously given?

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: your question could be rephrased as is the MFCC a linear transform

Comment: @BlackYasmin Thanks. I'll rephrase the question as per your suggestion.